# what's wrong with the following vb.net code?

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
             InitializeComponent();
         }

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As     System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
‘Define a variable for intNumber
 Dim intNumber As Integer
 ’Set the initial value
 intNumber = 27
 ‘Add 1 to the value of intNumber
 intNumber = intNumber + 1
 ‘Display the new value of intNumber
  MessageBox.Show("Value of intNumber + 1 = " & intNumber.ToString, _
  "Variables")
  End Sub
   }
  }
```

i am running this code in visual studio 2010 and getting tons of errors. here btnAdd is name of the button and clicking it shows a message box.what would be right code for same purpose.this code is from the book visual basic by karli davidson.

Comment: You are mixing C# and VB.NET - you added VB code to C# project

Answer (score 3):

> btnAdd_Click function is a vb.net code . You should use C# code for this function. Code is below

```
private void btnAdd_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
//Define a variable for intNumber
int intNumber = 0;
//Set the initial value
intNumber = 27;
//Add 1 to the value of intNumber
intNumber = intNumber + 1;
//Display the new value of intNumber
MessageBox.Show("Value of intNumber + 1 = " + intNumber.ToString, "Variables");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing VB.Net and C#. The function called "btnAdd_Click" should look like:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Define a variable for intNumber and set the initial value.
    int intNumber = 27;

    //Add 1 to the value of intNumber
    intNumber++; // This is shorthand format for intNumber = intNumber + 1

    //Display the new value of intNumber
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Value of intNumber + 1 = {0}", intNumber), "Variables");
}
```